# Cloned Sites and Original Site Are All Affecting Each Other

Tags: database, aegir

I am using Aegir to clone my Drupal 7 sites. I don't have any caching enabled on the original site.

When I clone the site everything appears to work correctly, however changes to the drupal database are mirrored between all my sites. For example, adding a new user will add the user to all the sites.

I have verified that separate databases are specified for each of the sites.

Any ideas what would be causing this?

Comment: Have you verified that separate databases are getting _updated_ for each of the sites?

Comment: This is definitely not normal behavior. Does the original site have aliases for the other sites names? As @Clive suggested it would be good to check via phpMyAdmin or a similar tool that the new user record is visible in all databases?

Comment: @Clive Yes I have verified that the actual database table is being updated for each of the sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I have a wildcard SSL setup for my server. By default when you clone a site in Aegir it does not set it up as SSL. However, I was still able to access the cloned site via HTTPS.

**The issue was caused by accessing the site via HTTPS when SSL was not enabled in Aegir for that specific site.**

**As soon as I enabled SSL for the site in Aegir the problem went away.**

I'm not exactly sure what was going on in the backend. It would be great if someone could chime in on that...